# Moduli Space of Elliptic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, moduli-space

I am trying to see that:

> The moduli space of Riemann surfaces of genus 1 with one marked point is $\mathbb{H}/PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

I know the facts that $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ acts on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ through holomorphic automorphisms and two elliptic curves $E_\tau, E_\mu$ are isomorphic $\tau$ and $\mu$ are related by a modular transformation (i.e. elements of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}$).

It would be very helpful if some explains it from a completely analytic and geometric point of view. The definition of moduli space I am working with is: The moduli space $\mathfrak{M}_{g,n}$ is the set of isomorphism classes of Riemann surfaces of genus $g$ with $n$ reference points marked.

Comment: What's more to say?  The marked point is identified with the zero of your elliptic curve.

Comment: @user10354138 I think I am missing something obvious ; but how do I see the elements of $\mathbb{H}$ as automorphisms of the Torus?

Comment: $\mathbb{H}$ are not automorphisms of the torus.  You have every $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$ gives a complex structure on the torus, and they are equivalent iff $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are related by the faithful $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$-action on $\mathbb{H}$.  Conversely, given a complex structure and a marked point, you construct the period lattice and you have $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$-ambiguity in the generators, to make it to $\mathbb{H}$ you reduce it to $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ because you divide one by the other and select the one that is in $\mathbb{H}$, etc.

Comment: Thanks, so what should be $\mathfrak{M}_{1,0}$? It looks the same.

Comment: You can't define $\mathfrak{M}_{1,0}$ as an orbifold (because it has an infinite group of marked point  preserving automorphisms).  It still makes sense as sets, but that is rather useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upvoted comment above solves it for me. All credit goes to [user10354138](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/592552/user10354138).